# changing a function and creating a form to trigger it on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, hook

Hello Im looking to change a function of a wordpress plugin developed by Automattic. Called Co-authors-plus. They have created a WP-CLI command list for it and some. the function is here.

/**
     * Create author terms for all posts that don't have them
     *
     * @subcommand create-terms-for-posts
     */
    public function create_terms_for_posts() {
        global $coauthors_plus, $wp_post_types;

```
    // Cache these to prevent repeated lookups
    $authors = array();
    $author_terms = array();

    $args = array(
            'order'            => 'ASC',
            'orderby'          => 'ID',
            'post_type'         => $coauthors_plus->supported_post_types,
            'posts_per_page'    => 100,
            'paged'             => 1,
            'update_meta_cache' => false,
        );

    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    $affected = 0;
    $count = 0;
    $total_posts = $posts->found_posts;
    WP_CLI::line( "Now inspecting or updating {$posts->found_posts} total posts." );
    while ( $posts->post_count ) {

        foreach ( $posts->posts as $single_post ) {

            $count++;

            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $single_post->ID, $coauthors_plus->coauthor_taxonomy );
            if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
                WP_CLI::error( $terms->get_error_message() );
            }

            if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
                WP_CLI::line( "{$count}/{$posts->found_posts}) Skipping - Post #{$single_post->ID} '{$single_post->post_title}' already has these terms: " . implode( ', ', wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'name' ) ) );
                continue;
            }

            $author = ( ! empty( $authors[ $single_post->post_author ] ) ) ? $authors[ $single_post->post_author ] : get_user_by( 'id', $single_post->post_author );
            $authors[ $single_post->post_author ] = $author;

            $author_term = ( ! empty( $author_terms[ $single_post->post_author ] ) ) ? $author_terms[ $single_post->post_author ] : $coauthors_plus->update_author_term( $author );
            $author_terms[ $single_post->post_author ] = $author_term;

            wp_set_post_terms( $single_post->ID, array( $author_term->slug ), $coauthors_plus->coauthor_taxonomy );
            WP_CLI::line( "{$count}/{$total_posts}) Added - Post #{$single_post->ID} '{$single_post->post_title}' now has an author term for: " . $author->user_nicename );
            $affected++;
        }

        if ( $count && 0 === $count % 500 ) {
            $this->stop_the_insanity();
            sleep( 1 );
        }

        $args['paged']++;
        $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    }
    WP_CLI::line( 'Updating author terms with new counts' );
    foreach ( $authors as $author ) {
        $coauthors_plus->update_author_term( $author );
    }

    WP_CLI::success( "Done! Of {$total_posts} posts, {$affected} now have author terms." );

}
```

`

I want to remove the requirement where the post is required not to have a term, so that the end result is that the new co-author is appended to the existing author. this is the first change.

the second change would be to create a form (possibly with a shortcode to display in front end) where the current_user is automatically added to the field and is submitted as co-author upon form submission.

any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you